# Redirect old links with parameters by .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Still working on my Joomla 2.5-site, now I realized old links on Google and on other sites I'd like to 301 rewrite:

```
http://www.my-site.com/index.php?p=26
```

to lead to

```
http://www.my-site.com/new-link.html
```

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?p=26$ /new-link.html [L,R=301]
```

but this didn't work.

I'd like to add that I need specific rewrites, e.g. index.php?p=26 --> new-link.html, ...p=99 --> another-link.html etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that won't work since you can't match QUERY_STRING in `RewriteRule`.

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /new-link.html? [L,R=301]
```

**EDIT:**

Writing rules specific IDs:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?p=26(?:&|\s) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /new-link.html? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?p=12345(?:&|\s) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /another-link.html? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I can't really read it, but it seems it would rewrite `p=26`, `p=99`, `p=12345` to `/new-link.html`? I need those rewritten to different pages.

Comment: Well in that case you will need different rules for each id OR make use of `RewriteMap` if you have server access.

Comment: how do I write a rule for a specific id? Thank you in advance.